# Implementation of a web-server

Tags: java, multithreading, webserver, implementation, node.js

I had like to implement my own web-server in pure Java
the web-server should support only static resources (i.e. html, js, css, pics, movies etc..)

Can you recommend a tutorial or an article on how to implement such a thing?
should I use few processes or a thread-pool or should I consider a loop-event oriented like NodeJS?

I know there are free web-servers that does exactly what I am looking for, but I had like to do it as an exersice to my self.

Comment: Download Apache Tomcat source code and see how they did theirs?

Comment: @Gentleman: I wouldn't even try that. Tomcat is way too boosted with too many config opportunities, valves, extensions, simply too just to see how requests are handled in order to return file contents...

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I tried that once... That thing is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend familiarizing yourself with the HTTP request format http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2616/.  Implementing HTTP from scratch is no small feat, but it is certainly a good learning exercise.

Within Java itself for simplicity I recommend using a thread-per-request server - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html - that using `java.nio` for serving files.  In a concurrent setting `java.nio` is preferable to `java.io` because it balances load better.  You will likely find benchmarks that suggest that `java.io` is faster, but that is for sequential single-threaded code.

Comment: Might be better to try java.nio2 if you don't mind using the JDK 7 early access.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this as an exercise, I'd recommend an event-driven model.

I don't think there's one tutorial on this topic because the knowledge required is so far-ranging - the HTTP protocol, file access, threading and concurrency, configuration-file management, socket communication, logging, error handling, MIME types...  Yeah, even just sharing static resources, it's still a biggie.

Read up, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is what you want
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/Webserver/

Comment: why multithreading is the right approch?

Comment: Depends on traffic and the purpose of the web server, if you're going to serve only static pages, i think that it is the simpler and better approach. If you're going to use comet or you're going to have a lot off concurrent traffic event driven is better, you don't need one thread per request blocked while the connection is open.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the ACME web server interesting as a starting point.  We use it for ad-hoc file transfers. When you have familarized yourself with it, you can see if you can discover its bottlenecks and then ponder on how to fix it :)

http://acme.com/java/software/Acme.Serve.Serve.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) to do the job. It lets you specify Encoders/Decoders to deal with the HTT Protocol properly and calls a method when a request arrives etc. It handles thread management internally. I never start a networking project without it.