# How to get started on making an http server?

Tags: java, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementation of a web-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362855/implementation-of-a-web-server)

I am trying to make an http server in java that can handle http requests.  if the user types in http://www.example.com/Weather/94901 i want the program to be able to get the string "Weather/94901" then have my application process that and then display to results in the text of the webpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051989/a-java-http-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you write a web server for that? In PHP, for example, you could use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` or in JSP `request.getPathInfo()`

Or if you really must, start with [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org) for example, an already existing Java HTTP server